# Java encrypt AES, PHP decrypt AES

Tags: java, php, encryption, cryptography, aes

I was looking for a way to encrypt a string in Java, and decrypt it in PHP. I found [this](http://www.logikdev.com/2010/11/01/encrypt-with-php-decrypt-with-java/) in an answer somewhere on Stackoverflow and I modified it to do the exact opposite.
This is my code to encrypt in Java:

```
public static String encrypt(String data, String initialVectorString, String secretKey) {
        String encryptedData = null;
        try {
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(md5(secretKey).substring(0, 16).getBytes(), "AES");
            IvParameterSpec initialVector = new IvParameterSpec(initialVectorString.getBytes());
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB8/NoPadding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, initialVector);
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes());
            byte[] base64encrypted = (new org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64()).encode(encrypted);
            encryptedData = new String(base64encrypted, "UTF-8");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return encryptedData;
    }
```

and this is my code to decrypt in PHP:

```
function decrypt($message, $initialVector, $secretKey) {
        return (
        mcrypt_decrypt( 
        MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
        substr(md5($secretKey), 0, 16),
        base64_decode($message),  
        MCRYPT_MODE_CFB,
        $initialVector
        )
        );
    }
```

The secret key and initial vector change every time.
The code works for 90% of the time, but sometimes it only partially decrypts the string and the remaining characters are unreadable like this: `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.1��×` which should say `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]`. Did I make any mistakes modifying the code?

EDIT: I may need to add that decrypting in Java using the code from the link above DOES work.

EDIT2: Found the answer, it was a stupid mistake, PHP got the + in a base64 encrypted string as space. Thanks for all of your help, I will still be using alot of it.

Comment: Does it fail 10% of the time on the same string, i.e passing "Hello world" 10 times works correctly only 9 times out of 10? Or do you mean passing in 10 different strings results on one of them being broken? I'm not sure if this is your problem but one thing to note is that you have to have the proper number of bytes in the base64 string. If you don't have the proper amount, the decoding can give you different results. Try adding padding to the end of the base64 string if needed.

Comment: This code really insecure. Although your "key" contains 16 characters, but since those characters are hexits each of them contains only 4 bit (instead of 8 bit if you actually had used raw binary output). So your key has only 64 bit which is brute-forceable nowadays.

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution, are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: Just wondering why you are using `CFB8` mode.

Comment: It's probably the base 64 string being modified because it hasn't been properly URL-encoded. Compare ciphertext and IV's before decoding them. Note that `initialVectorString.getBytes()` is likely to cause failures as well, although it would not result in this particular problem.

Comment: @EugenHotaj It fails about about 10% of the time with the same string being encrypted, but with a different key and iv. I noticed that longer strings have a higher percentage of failing.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thanks alot of for the tip! I'll definately make sure to fix that.

Comment: @zaph On why CFB8: I am completely new to cryptography. I used the code from the site I linked in the question and that one used CFB8 too. Thanks for the tip on not using mcrypt, I didn't know it was abandoned. I'll look into the links you gave.

Comment: Typically AES with CBC mode is used along with PKCS padding and a random IV prepended to the encrypted data.

Comment: If you're free to use whatever you like, then you should consider using [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor). It's really secure and provides implementations for different languages, so that you don't need to think about the specifics of the cryptographic primitives.